# The nuget packages nightmare in VS 15.5.1

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution with 15 projects. To better manage my references/dependencies, I have gathered all shared nuget packages in one .net core project. All projects requiring these packages have to reference it.

This works fine but it becomes a nightmare to update nuget packages.

Few days ago, a newer version of X.PagedList was released. After updatin the package, I got the following error messages

> Assembly 'XXX' with identity 'XXX' uses 'X.PagedList v7.2.0 ...' which
>   has a higher version than referenced assembly 'X.PagedList' with
>   identity 'X.PagedList v7.1'

I tried to clean the solution, rebuild, remove/re-add the nuget package with no luck. I ended-up removing the nuget cache, restarting my computer and restoring all nuget packages... That can't be the easiest solution.

Earlier this month, I had similar issues. I was not getting an error, but it was like all my references were gone. All my import statements were detected as errors...

Am I the only one experiencing that kind of issues? Is there a way to make package update easier?

My environment:
Visual studio 2017 Community 15.5.1
ReSharper 2017.2.2
AWS Toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Delete the .vs directory in your solution folder or the folder above it.  This is magic.

2.) Open the .config file in every project and delete all the binding redirects.

3.) Delete bin and obj folders for all projects.

Comment: omg that's interesting. Is this a bug that will be fixed eventually?